# Spring Hibernate "You cannot commit during a managed transaction!"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, jboss7.x

After upgrading my application from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.1 I have the following Spring Hibernate exception when trying to login:

```
DEBUG,[interceptor.ExceptionInterceptor][],org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit Hibernate transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: commit failed
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:472)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:392)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at myapp.aop.interceptor.MethodExceptionInterceptor.invoke(MethodExceptionInterceptor.java:21)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at myapp.aop.interceptor.SessionActivityInterceptor.invoke(SessionActivityInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy121.endSession(Unknown Source)
    at myapp.web.action.connection.ConnectionBean.connect(ConnectionBean.java:100)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:22)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInvocationContext.proceed(RootInvocationContext.java:32)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:56)
    at myapp.web.interceptor.ExceptionInterceptor.aroundInvoke(ExceptionInterceptor.java:42)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.transaction.RollbackInterceptor.aroundInvoke(RollbackInterceptor.java:28)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.core.MethodContextInterceptor.aroundInvoke(MethodContextInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.core.SynchronizationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SynchronizationInterceptor.java:35)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInterceptor.invoke(RootInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.interceptInvocation(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:186)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.invoke(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:104)
    at myapp.web.action.connection.ConnectionBean_$$_javassist_seam_2.connect(ConnectionBean_$$_javassist_seam_2.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:335)
    at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:348)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstPropertySuffix.invoke(AstPropertySuffix.java:58)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:96)
    at org.jboss.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.MethodExpressionMethodBinding.invoke(MethodExpressionMethodBinding.java:46)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:101)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXCommand.broadcast(UIXCommand.java:190)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:786)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1251)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._invokeApplication(LifecycleImpl.java:1074)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:402)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:225)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:105)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:502)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:502)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:327)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:229)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at myapp.web.filter.SessionActivityFilter.doFilter(SessionActivityFilter.java:67)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:40)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:90)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:389)
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
 Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: commit failed
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:185)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:468)
    ... 93 more
 Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: unable to commit against JDBC connection
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:178)
    ... 94 more
 Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: You cannot commit during a managed transaction!
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.jdbcCommit(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:1052)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.commit(WrappedConnection.java:757)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:112)
    ... 95 more
```

Here is my spring beans configuration :

```
    <bean id="parentSessionFactory" abstract="true">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="myDS" />
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
                    org.h2.Driver
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_structured_cache">true</prop>                            
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="myDS"
          class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:/myDS" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="sessionFactory" parent="parentSessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">   
      <property name="configLocation">
        <value>
            classpath:model/hibernate.cfg.xml
        </value>
      </property>

      <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props merge="true">
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
            </prop>    
        </props>        
      </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
      <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="sessionFactory"/>
      </property>
    </bean>


    <!-- the transactional advice (i.e. what 'happens'; see the <aop:advisor/> bean below) -->
    <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <!-- the transactional semantics... -->
      <tx:attributes>
        <!-- all methods starting with 'get' are read-only -->
        <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" />
        <tx:method name="find*" read-only="true" />
        <tx:method name="list*" read-only="true" />
        <tx:method name="read*" read-only="true" />
        <tx:method name="save*" read-only="false" isolation="READ_COMMITTED"/>
        <tx:method name="remove*" read-only="false" isolation="READ_COMMITTED"/>
        <tx:method name="refresh*" read-only="false" isolation="READ_COMMITTED"/>
        <tx:method name="delete*" read-only="false" isolation="READ_COMMITTED"/>
        <!-- other methods use the default transaction settings (see below) -->
        <tx:method name="*" />
      </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<!-- ensure that the above transactional advice runs for any execution
    of an operation defined by the *Service interface -->
    <aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="serviceOperation"
                      expression="execution(* services..*Service*.*(..))" />
        <aop:pointcut id="daoOperation"
                      expression="execution(* dao..*Dao.*(..))" />


        <aop:advisor advice-ref="sessionActivityInterceptor"
                     pointcut-ref="serviceOperation" />         
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="exceptionInterceptor"
                     pointcut-ref="serviceOperation" />      -->
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice"
                     pointcut-ref="serviceOperation" />
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice"
                     pointcut-ref="daoOperation" />      
    </aop:config>
```

Here is the hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>
<!--        <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider</property> -->
        <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>


        <!-- Several mapping classes here -->
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The `@Transactional` annotation is only used in one method in my application and in my unit tests, but is not used for what concerns the login part of the app.

Investigating my exception further I see the code that throw the exception in `BaseWrapperManagedConnection` from `ironjacamar-jdbc-1.0.17` :

```
/**
    * JDBC commit
    * @exception SQLException Thrown if an error occurs
    */
   void jdbcCommit() throws SQLException
   {
      synchronized (stateLock)
      {
         if (inManagedTransaction)
            throw new SQLException("You cannot commit during a managed transaction!");

         if (jdbcAutoCommit)
            throw new SQLException("You cannot commit with autocommit set!");
      }
      con.commit();

      if (mcf.isJTA().booleanValue())
      {
         if (inLocalTransaction.getAndSet(false))
         {
            Collection<ConnectionEventListener> copy = null;
            synchronized (cels)
            {
               copy = new ArrayList<ConnectionEventListener>(cels);
            }

            ConnectionEvent ce = new ConnectionEvent(this, ConnectionEvent.LOCAL_TRANSACTION_COMMITTED);

            for (Iterator<ConnectionEventListener> i = copy.iterator(); i.hasNext();)
            {
               ConnectionEventListener cel = i.next();
               try
               {
                  cel.localTransactionCommitted(ce);
               }
               catch (Throwable t)
               {
                  if (trace)
                     getLog().trace("Error notifying of connection committed for listener: " + cel, t);
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

the variable `inManagedTransaction` is set to true in `LocalManagedConnection` begin method from `ironjacamar-jdbc-1.0.17` :

```
/**
    * {@inheritDoc}
    */
   public void begin() throws ResourceException
   {
      lock();
      try
      {
         synchronized (stateLock)
         {
            if (!inManagedTransaction)
            {
               try
               {
                  if (underlyingAutoCommit)
                  {
                     underlyingAutoCommit = false;
                     con.setAutoCommit(false);
                  }
                  checkState();
                  inManagedTransaction = true;
               }
               catch (SQLException e)
               {
                  checkException(e);
               }
            }
            else
               throw new ResourceException("Trying to begin a nested local tx");
         }
      }
      finally
      {
         unlock();
      }
   }
```

And the only place where this `inManagedTransaction` is set to false is in `LocalManagedConnection` `commit()` or `rollback()` method :

```
/**
    * {@inheritDoc}
    */
   public void commit() throws ResourceException
   {
      lock();
      try
      {
         synchronized (stateLock)
         {
            if (inManagedTransaction)
               inManagedTransaction = false;
         }
         try
         {
            con.commit();
         }
         catch (SQLException e)
         {
            checkException(e);
         }
      }
      finally
      {
         unlock();
      }
   }

   /**
    * {@inheritDoc}
    */
   public void rollback() throws ResourceException
   {
      lock();
      try
      {
         synchronized (stateLock)
         {
            if (inManagedTransaction)
               inManagedTransaction = false;
         }
         try
         {
            con.rollback();
         }
         catch (SQLException e)
         {
            try
            {
               checkException(e);
            }
            catch (Exception e2)
            {
               // Ignore
            }
         }
      }
      finally
      {
         unlock();
      }
   }
```

**Is it normal that I have two ManagedConnection one is `BaseWrapperManagedConnection` and the other `LocalManagedConnection` and that I'm going through both of their commit method ?**

I have also read that JBoss could also take care of transactions (container managed transactions).  Is it possible that both Spring and JBoss try to handle my sessions and transactions ?

I'm using Hibernate 4.2 and Spring 3.2.0.
Most of it is classical configuration like found on many tutorials on the web nothing fancy.  The application using this configuration was working using JSF 1.2.
Thanks for any advices, hints.

Comment: Judging from the stack trace you are opening and closing sessions yourself instead of letting spring handle that for you. I also wonder why do you mix both classic transaction config (xml and point cuts) and `@Transactional` that will, at some point, bite you. JSF 1.2 and 2.x changed considerably upgrading isn't simply replacing a jar but takes a bit more work (in my experience).

Comment: How do you see I'm using     @Transactional ?  Actually I'm not using this annotation, except in my tests.

Comment: @M.Deinum, how can I check if I open/close session myself ?  But I don't think it is the case in my code, but maybe jsf 2.1 or jboss seam is opening/closing session ?

Comment: There is `<tx:annotation-driven />` which is quite a give away. You have a `ConnectionBean` which is from your own hand which does something with the connection, hence my suggestion that you are probably doing things yourself with the connection/session which you shouldn't be doing...

Comment: Another thing is why are you combining JBoss Seam with Spring? Generally trying to bolt together the 2 frameworks will eventually clash.

Comment: That connection bean is handling the user connection.  Then with the aop configuration there are services method calls, and it end up by doing a commit.  All is handled by Spring actually, I'm not opening/closing sessions.  For JBoss Seam it is plan to remove it, but I'm doing things step by step.  I'm close to make it work, only this managed connection problem remain.

Comment: So you are messing around with connections yourself... I would say that JBoss Seam is part of the problem as that is also trying to do commits and thinks it is a local connection instead of managed connection. I would strongly suggest removing that first....

Comment: Well the advantage of JBoss Seam is that it was possible to inject Spring Beans into Seam components using the @In annotation.  That is not possible with CDI, so it might not be so good option for me to remove JBoss Seam right away.

Comment: You now have competing frameworks for managing your transactions, connections etc. Which will bite you and give you weird issues (like this one). You can see in your stack trace that both spring and seam do stuff with your custom connection bean (probably opening 2 connections 1 managed  the other unmanaged), when the spring part end it will try to close the connection but cannot because it isn't a managed one. So the problem is somewhere in either the fact that you combine Seam and Spring or how you are opening connections yourself...

Comment: Yes I understand, sorry for basic question like this one, but how can I check exactly how am I opening connections myself ?

Comment: You want to look at your `ConnectionBean` that seems to be doing things with the session and connection and seems custom (maybe you can add it to your question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably configured a JTA DataSource in JBoss, which is a managed transactional resource and then you are using a non-JTA `HibernateTransactionManager`.

To fix it, you have two options:

1. You either use a RESOURCE_LOCAL DataSource and provide it via JNDI
2. You keep the JTA DataSource and configure Hibernate to use the [Spring JtaTransactionManager](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-transaction-isolation-levels-in-enterprise-java/) with the actual [Arjuna Transaction Manager](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/JBossTransactionsWithSpring)

Comment: It was this.  JBoss was configured to use JTA by default.  It's fixed now, thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

if your data source uses jta you must not call transaction.begin neither commit those transaction demarcation are called by the container.
if your data source uses RESOURCE_LOCAL you have to demarcate all your transaction even read only ones.